# Rigidbody not sticking to box object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity3D and I'm having a weird issue that I could not find a solution to it online.
I attached a rigid body component to a box object and added force to it using the update method in a script.. I used a function AddForce.

However, when I press play, the rigidbody is getting the force, but not the box itself.. i.e. the rigidbody is flying, but not the box
[image]

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out the reason.. I clicked on Static next to the object .. silly me